# Can code be deployed straight from the CRM?

Tags: deployment, ide

I've got a bit of a head-thumper on my hands. I've got test cases for two new triggers written, and in the Developer Console in my sandbox, it says my code coverage for all tests is 87%. However, when I refresh everything in Eclipse and try and deploy it, it says I only have a 71% code coverage.

I'm actually trying JUST to deploy changes to the test classes (more tests, more robust tests, etc) so trigger deployment will (in theory) go smoother.

Is there a way to deploy code to production straight from the CRM instead of mucking around in this Eclipse business?

Thanks!

Comment: look into change sets, but your problem may lay elsewhere : lower code coverage on production, you may need to also deploy some test classes for other stuff: just a guess.

Comment: The thing is, I successfully deployed a new test and trigger a couple of weeks ago, and have made no additional changes in that time, except for what I'm trying to deploy now.

Comment: Do you have tests that are relying on existing data in the org?  That could cause coverage to be affected.

Comment: There is one that was written buy the previous Salesforce guy a few years ago, but those haven't changed since my last deployment.

Comment: If you really think it's Eclipse causing the problem then, you should try change sets.  They're pretty easy to use and it takes Eclipse out of the equation.

Comment: I don't know what change sets is. Can you point me towards relevant information, and does it work on Linux?

Comment: Change Sets are a web-based deployment tool within Salesforce. [Getting Started With Change Sets](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000006751&language=en_US) What is the code coverage in your production org when you run all tests there (without performing a deployment)? I suspect your production org will not currently surpass 75%. In order to deploy anything new into production you would need to correct the root cause of that lack of coverage in your sandbox and also deploy those changes with your new code.

Comment: Alright, let's assume that I've got insufficient code coverage in Production - Why would I have been able to deploy a trigger/test combo two weeks ago without issues? Also, why in instances when I'm only trying to deploy new and updated test methods to production does it give me just as much grief?

Comment: some changes may have been made on production that break existing test code (new validation rules for instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would direct you here:  http://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/changesets.htm

> A change set is a means by which one organization can send customizations to another organization. For example, you could create a new object in a sandbox organization and send it to your production organization using a change set.

That's far, far easier when working with a small list of known items.  I only use Eclipse when  its a bigger job.

Answer (score 1):

Have you updated your Eclipse IDE plug-in? That's always worth checking when Eclipse is misbehaving.

I also advocate using the Change Set, but if you're determined to use Eclipse (maybe for version control), you could also try installing the Force.com IDE, a standalone version of the Eclipse IDE with the plug-in built in. It operates on 3.5.2 Galileo build of Eclipse, slightly behind the supported 3.6 most people download.